# Access input hidden field Title attribute from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a HTML hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" title="aaa" value="bbb"  id="TAB" runat="server" />
```

I want to access the title attribute from the code behind, like if its a input="text", there is a option TAB.ToolTip, but not for "hidden". Is it possible to get the title since it exists like an attribute?

Comment: <input type="hidden" title="aaa" value="bbb"  id="TAB" runat="server" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your control is recognized by the webserver as a HtmlInputHidden instance. You should be able to fetch all attributes of the control using the Attributes property (see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes(v=vs.90)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.attributes%28v=vs.90%29))

In you code behind:

```
TAB.Attributes["title"] = "aaa";
```